# Add a watermark to PDF file that is being streamed by a 3rd party software using IIS

Tags: file, pdf, iis, intercept

My client is using some 3rd party web application, where users can download reports  in PDF (and other formats they choose). IIS is a web server.
I have a task to add a watermark to PDF files only without making any changes to that 3rd party application code. I do not have much experience in web technologies, but I was thinking to intercept the downloaded PDF file, call some utility to add a watermark and stream it back to the user.

Just started researching on http module and handlers but not sure if I'm moving in the right direction. Appreciate your input on implementation of this task